# Show a closable block if environment is local or staging

Tags: php, laravel, view

Using Laravel, I'd like to show fellow developers and staff on local / staging environments that they're viewing a certain template.

I've looked at a ServiceProvider, but could not get it to push a blade view into the top of the page.

My ServiceProvider is as follows :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

Class TemplateServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
     public function boot()
     {
         View::composer('*', function ($view)
         {
             $environment = App::environment();

             if (App::environment(['local', 'staging']))
             {
                 return view('frontend.shared.chosen-template');
             }
         });
     }
}
```

But the blade template is not being loaded.

I'd ideally like the Bootstrap Dismissable alert so users can close it down, If needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is share a variable to all views like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->share('isProduction', !App::environment(['local', 'staging']));
}
```

Or alternatively just to a specific layout:

```
public function boot()
{
    app('view')->composer('layouts.master', function ($view) {
        $view->with(['isProduction' => !App::environment(['local', 'staging'])]);
    }
}
```

Then in your main layout (e.g. layouts/master.blade.php at the top of your body) you can include this specific view:

```
@if(!$isProduction)
    @include('frontend.shared.chosen-template')
@endif
```